# How do I redirect my audio output to USB speaker from laptop?

Tags: speakers

I am running ubuntu in Dell Inspiron . Previously when I used windows vista , my USB speakers (logitech) worked well . Now when I connect to ubuntu , it is not working.

Any idea how to send the audio output to the USB speakers?

Comment: did you check to see if they're recognized by the OS? post the output of 'lsusb'

Comment: Yes.They are recognized.

Comment: click on the sound menu, go to sound preferences and in the output tab look for something like USB Speakers if it's there just make sure it's ticked off and it should work.

Comment: Glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Click on the Sound Menu
- Go to Sound Preferences
- Select the Output tab
- Select USB Speakers from the list